При работе автотестов не выдаётся разрешение спец. возможностей
Есть приложение под Андроид. Оно требует для работы разрешения службы специальных возможностей. При включении этой настройки вручную всё работает как надо. Если же эту службу включает автотест, появляется следующая ошибка: "Сервис работает некорректно, Нажмите, чтобы узнать больше". Можете подсказать, в чём может быть проблема и как это можно обойти?

Добавьте в вопрос как "эту службу включает автотест". Не помешает и версия Андроид и устройство на котором тесты запускаются.

Версия Android 13. Телефон Infinix NOTE 30.
Службу автотест включает имитируя действия пользователя. Нажимает кнопку в приложении, его перебрасывает в настройки и через настройки включает.
Пробовал выдавать права через RuleChain.outerRule(GrantPermissionRule.grant(android.Manifest.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE)), но в этом случае выдаёт ошибку junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Failed to grant permissions

Непонятно как может быть разница между включением вручную и кликами автотеста. BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE не надо запрашивать, достаточно декларации: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57150110/5479247

Я тоже думал, что разницы быть не должно. Но при включении вручную всё работает как надо, при работе автотеста это разрешение не выдаётся. Тумблер переключается, но в итоге разрешение не выдано и в настройках у этого разрешения ошибка "Сервис работает некорректно". С остальными 4 разрешениями проблем не возникало
При попытке выдать через GrantPermissionRule на 2 из 5 разрешениях ошибка. На этом и выдаче прав администратора приложению.
